# Embded Python Import Ctypes fails

Tags: c#, python, ctypes

I'm using Python for .Net using python 2.7, I copied All the needed directories from the Python2.7 into my Application Directory
when I try to import ctypes, in the interactive shell

```
import ctypes
```

the Error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\TesetPyNet\bin\Debug\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

what I'm asking is there is any away to set the path to the Dll folder.

Note: when I embeded python 3.4.3 into my c# app and copied the Directories of python run-time into my app directory, It worked fine with importing ctypes, even on OS with no already Installed versions of python

Comment: the failior is not only when importing ctypes, but when I import any module requires build-in module in Dll folder

Comment: It's looking for the extension module `_ctypes.pyd`, which is normally in `Python27\DLLs`.

Comment: the weird thing that it is really in Python\DLLs

Answer (score 0):

After some digging and inspection, _ctypes.pyd is nothing but an OS specific (dynamic link library'for windows'-Shared object 'for UNIX like')

So when I inspected its dependencies,unlike python27.dll that depeneds on msvcr100.dll.It depends on msvcr90.dll

so the solution is Only to copy msvcr90.dll into the working directory of the application OR the DLLs directory, beside _ctypes.pyd

Comment: The official python27.dll is linked with msvcr90.dll. Did you build python27.dll yourself using VS 2010, and if so, why didn't you also build the extension modules?

Comment: yes it may be the case, I had to build python27.dll to trace some fatal errors when runing python code in c# app, so I get confused between the 2 copies of python27.dll